# Why does my answer have no value? Obviously there can be no better answer

Tags: discussion

[Open source code with no license... can I fork it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it/364781?noredirect=1#comment794415_364781)

Comment: This question could belong on meta softwareengineering. But you really should read what the comment on your answer says. It says there is no ADDED value. Answering a question with no new information, basically rewriting answers that are 5 years old is not a good idea. And you are wrong stating that there cannot be a better answer. There already is and have been for 5 years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the etiquette for repeat answers?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/889/whats-the-etiquette-for-repeat-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Your answer has value. It just adds no value to the question over the existing answers, especially [the top voted and accepted answer that provides a good explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148165/4) or [the one that cites the Github Terms of Service](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/270209/4). It was also posted 5 years later, where the situation hasn't changed and all of the answers are still correct.

New answers to a question should include new information, not a repeat of existing information.